# Why should use Version Control software rather a wordprocessor

Tags: version-control

A word-processor has most if not all the features of a version control software without the gobbledegook and the complexity. You can set a word-processor to always keep history and probably save as versions every time you save. You could have an online word-processor- if one doesn't exist then it sounds like a great opportunity- with general access to allow multiple users to access it.  Git and others are acknowledged to have multiple issues but I can't see a word-processor having big issues so why the preference for version control software?

Answer (score 2):

- Word processors, as far as I know, do not track versions of directory structures (trees) of files as a whole... .they only track single files.  A version control system treats a "snapshot" of a whole tree of files as a single unit.
- Online word processors do not support multiple authors working on the same file independently... instead they assume that multiple authors are collaborating in real time, working on exactly the same thing, which is not the usual workflow for software development.
- Word processors do not support the concept of branches, which are a powerful tool for many software development use cases